# Nginx SSl not disabling RC4 SSL Labs test

Tags: nginx

Nginx I am unable to disable RC4 cyphers in ssl_ciphers configuration

Multiple examples from around the web but I cannot get nginx to disable RC4 
Build of Nginx is 1.14.2 with openSSL 1.0.1h

I have tried Mozilla recommended setting
Tried !RC4 with numerous variants

Not sure what i'm missing here.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem;

ssl                        on;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling               on;
ssl_stapling_verify        on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
```

Comment: Where is this file included into your Nginx configuration?

Comment: In the end this config worked. SSL labs result in  an A.

The issue was between the keyboard and the chair: I testing the wrong container address. OOPS